# Traffic shaping & monthly traffic limit in Tomato?

Tags: dd-wrt, tomato, openwrt

Is there a way to do a monthly traffic limit in Tomato, DDWRT or OpenWRT in addition to the regular QoS?

This is for a house with several students sharing the internet.

I.e. for a specific IP address, IP Range or MAC address, the firmware will count the download traffic for that month.  When a configurable limit is set, it'll either limit it to say 64kbit/s up/down or drop all traffic and maybe redirect web traffic to an internal web server telling them that they have exceeded their quota.

How can this be done with those firmwares?

Comment: What are you expecting/wishing to have happen when the limit is reached?  Which traffic are you aiming to cap, WAN?

Comment: Yes WAN traffic.  I see gargoyle might do what I want.

Comment: Well if it turns out it does, perhaps add it as an answer. :)  I still recommend editing your question to include what you want to have happen when the limit is reached (cut WAN? for everyone?), as it may make it more clear/searchable for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

It looks like http://www.gargoyle-router.com/
Provides those very features and it's based on OpenWRT.

Tomato doesn't appear to support this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Use Gargoyle. It is almost impossible to build rules with the *unsupported* quota match of iptables in dd-wrt/openwrt.